# Default value with shell expressions in Dockerfile ARG and ENV

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I'd like to receive the version number as a single argument and extract major/minor numbers for various places in URLs at the RUN scripts in a Dockerfile.

```
ARG CUDA_VERSION
ARG CUDNN_VERSION

ENV CUDA_FULL="${CUDA_VERSION:-8.0.61_375.26}" \
    CUDA_MAJOR="$(echo ${CUDA_VERSION:-8.0.61_375.26} | cut -d. -f1)" \
    CUDA_MINOR="$(echo ${CUDA_VERSION:-8.0.61_375.26} | cut -d. -f2)" \
    CUDA_MAJMIN="$CUDA_MAJOR.$CUDA_MINOR"
ENV CUDNN_FULL="${CUDNN_VERSION:-7.0.1}" \
    CUDNN_MAJOR="$(echo ${CUDNN_VERSION:-7.0.1} | cut -d. -f1)" \
    CUDNN_MINOR="$(echo ${CUDNN_VERSION:-7.0.1} | cut -d. -f2)" \
    CUDNN_MAJMIN="$CUDNN_MAJOR.$CUDNN_MINOR"

RUN curl -LO https://.../${CUDNN_FULL}/.../...${CUDA_MAJMIN}...
```

If I try the above, the shell expressions are not evaluated and just pasted as-is in the later RUN scripts.

Would be there better way to achieve this, without creating an external shell scripts that wraps this Dockerfile?

Comment: I cannot believe that there is still no elegant solution to fix that issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The ${variable_name} syntax also supports a few of the standard bash modifiers as specified below:
>
> ${variable:-word} indicates that if variable is set then the result will be that value. If variable is not set then word will be the result.
>
> ${variable:+word} indicates that if variable is set then word will be the result, otherwise the result is the empty string.

`ENV` is special docker build command and doesn't support this. What you are looking for is to run Shell commands in ENV. So this won't work.

Possible solution is to use a bash script

**cuda_version.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
CUDA_FULL="${CUDA_VERSION:-8.0.61_375.26}"
CUDA_MAJOR="$(echo ${CUDA_VERSION:-8.0.61_375.26} | cut -d. -f1)"
CUDA_MINOR="$(echo ${CUDA_VERSION:-8.0.61_375.26} | cut -d. -f2)"
CUDA_MAJMIN="$CUDA_MAJOR.$CUDA_MINOR" 
CUDNN_FULL="${CUDNN_VERSION:-7.0.1}"
CUDNN_MAJOR="$(echo ${CUDNN_VERSION:-7.0.1} | cut -d. -f1)"
CUDNN_MINOR="$(echo ${CUDNN_VERSION:-7.0.1} | cut -d. -f2)"
CUDNN_MAJMIN="$CUDNN_MAJOR.$CUDNN_MINOR"
```

And change your dockerfile to

```
ARG CUDA_VERSION=8.0.61_375.26
ARG CUDNN_VERSION=7.0.1

ENV CUDA_VERSION=${CUDA_VERSION} CUDNN_VERSION=${CUDNN_VERSION}
COPY cuda_version.sh /cuda_version.sh
RUN bash -c "source /cuda_version.sh && curl -LO https://.../${CUDNN_FULL}/.../...${CUDA_MAJMIN}..."
```

You can remove the default values from your shell file as they will always be there from the Dockerfile arguments/environment